# Eclipse Build Variables Relative to Path Variables

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, build, path

My project has external resource files linked to a folder on my computer. In order to change them easily when moving the project to another location or another PC, I defined a `Path Variable` called `LIBRARY_LOC` by going into:

```
Properties/Resource/Linked Resources/Path Variables.
```

Now I am able to add a file by going into:

```
New/File/Advanced/Link to file in the file system/Variables/LIBRARY_LOC
```

Then complete the relative link as:

```
LIBRARY_LOC\utility\some_file.c
```

So I can add an externally linked file using the relative location defined as `LIBRARY_LOC`.

Everything works fine for now.

Now I also need to add `Include Paths` using `LIBRARY_LOC` into `Tool Settings/GCC Compiler/Include paths`

So I tried this:

```
${LIBRARY_LOC}/Utilities/sequencer
```

or this:

```
${env_var:LIBRARY_LOC}/Utilities/sequencer
```

or this:

```
LIBRARY_LOC/Utilities/sequencer
```

But none of them worked. The only way to achieve this is to define a `Build Variable` with a different name but pointing to the same location. Let's say `LIBRARY_PATH`. Then I can use this in `Include Paths` as below:

```
"{LIBRARY_PATH}/Utilities/sequencer
```

Now I am able to do what I want, I have relative paths for both adding externally linked files and include paths but when I move the project, I will need to change two different variables defined in `Path Variables` and `Build Variables` but in fact, they both point to the same location.

I tried referencing each other while defining them but it didn't work either. If it could work, I could at least change only one of them but keep the other as it would be defined as a relative to the other.